# How to create a system of events through interrupts in python

Tags: python, events, signals

Because of my zero knowledge about Python GUIs,
I need some help, to make a mechanism for,
Making requests through HTML,CSS or Ajax (node.js, Apache or nginx server) to a Python program to execute certain functions.

For example,
I have a python running a `while True:` loop, but at a given moment want perform an interrupt signal and sending data to execute a function a kind of events system.

First, I bind an event to program:

```
#program.bind(EVENT_NAME, EVENT_HANDLER)
program.bind(miaowcat, miaowfunc)
```

The program runs and any time an interrupt is performed, executing the function `miaowfunct` and passing the data of the event to `*args`

```
def miaowfunct(*args):
```

It's a prototype. So, `args` can be with numeric signals or other elements.

I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of problem is what [messaging systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) are designed to solve.

You write some code that needs to be executed at a trigger (this is called a *consumer*).

Your code that needs to execute the function (called a *producer*), creates a message and sends it to a broker.

The broker takes your message and puts it on a queue.

The *consumer* is listening on this queue for messages, when it sees one, it will "wake up", run itself, and then go back to sleep.

For Python, the following are typically used:

- Messaging Broker = [RabbitMQ](http://rabbitmq.com)
- Task Queue = [Celery](http://celeryproject.org)